# Grep like nearby lines from ElasticSearch

Tags: grep, elasticsearch, logstash

The application I'm debugging creates log files with many API calls logged as two events:

```
timestamp1 request_ip-->{$URL}
timestamp2 response_ip<--{$DATA}
```

I've recently started pouring the logs into ElasticSearch using LogStash (with Kibana as a web front).

Is there any way to do a search that includes nearby lines? Assume that request and response are always consecutive, if this helps.

With grep I would have done:

```
grep -A 1 "-->{$URL}"
```

How can I do the same with an existing LogStash+ElasticSearch deployment?

Comment: maybe something with a range of timestamps?

Comment: Please let me know if you found a solution for your problem, I'm interested in having the grep -A -B features in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is case of [multi-line filter in LogStash](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.0/filters/multiline). While I am not sure of exact details so I am not building RegEx for you, but your pattern would be around request_ip and "what" which connects multiple lines would be regex around response_ip. I am not sure if what I am saying is clear enough, but the documentation link should provide you the leads. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using multi-line with great success for some things, but it only works on consecutive lines. I suppose I'll have to add an option for the client (Kibana) to support a subquery of sorts.